# MvcScaffolding can't be installed due to some error occurred

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm using NuGet Packager Manager v1.5.20831.9017.

I'm using Package Manager Console to install MvcScaffolding.  There are some error occurred so that I can't `Add Controller` anymore.

The main error message is

> Unable to find type [T4Scaffolding.NuGetServices.Services.ScaffoldingPackagePathResolver]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Here is the detailed output when I installing MvcScaffolding.

```
PM> Install-Package MvcScaffolding
Attempting to resolve dependency 'T4Scaffolding'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework (≥ 4.1.10311.0)'.
You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=224682. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 4.1.10715.0'.
Successfully installed 'T4Scaffolding 1.0.4'.
Unable to find type [T4Scaffolding.NuGetServices.Services.ScaffoldingPackagePathResolver]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
at G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.4\tools\init.ps1:44 Char:72
+         [T4Scaffolding.NuGetServices.Services.ScaffoldingPackagePathResolver] <<<< ::SetPackagesRootDirectory($packagesRoot)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (T4Scaffolding.N...agePathResolver:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Update-FormatData : Cannot find a part of the path 'G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.2\tools\T4Scaffolding.Format.ps1xml'.
at G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.4\tools\init.ps1:46 Char:20
+         Update-FormatData <<<<  -PrependPath (Join-Path $toolsPath T4Scaffolding.Format.ps1xml)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-FormatData], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypesXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateFormatDataCommand

Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get install path because packages root directory has not been supplied
at G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.4\tools\init.ps1:50 Char:24
+         Set-DefaultScaffolder <<<<  -Name DbContext -Scaffolder T4Scaffolding.EFDbContext -SolutionWide -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-DefaultScaffolder], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.SetDefaultScaffolderCmdlet

Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get install path because packages root directory has not been supplied
at G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.4\tools\init.ps1:51 Char:24
+         Set-DefaultScaffolder <<<<  -Name Repository -Scaffolder T4Scaffolding.EFRepository -SolutionWide -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-DefaultScaffolder], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.SetDefaultScaffolderCmdlet

Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get install path because packages root directory has not been supplied
at G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.4\tools\init.ps1:52 Char:24
+         Set-DefaultScaffolder <<<<  -Name CustomTemplate -Scaffolder T4Scaffolding.CustomTemplate -SolutionWide -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-DefaultScaffolder], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.SetDefaultScaffolderCmdlet

Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get install path because packages root directory has not been supplied
at G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.4\tools\init.ps1:53 Char:24
+         Set-DefaultScaffolder <<<<  -Name CustomScaffolder -Scaffolder T4Scaffolding.CustomScaffolder -SolutionWide -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-DefaultScaffolder], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.SetDefaultScaffolderCmdlet

Successfully installed 'MvcScaffolding 1.0.4'.
Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get install path because packages root directory has not been supplied
at G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.4\tools\init.ps1:35 Char:22
+ Set-DefaultScaffolder <<<<  -Name Controller -Scaffolder MvcScaffolding.Controller -SolutionWide -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-DefaultScaffolder], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.SetDefaultScaffolderCmdlet

Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get install path because packages root directory has not been supplied
at G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.4\tools\init.ps1:36 Char:22
+ Set-DefaultScaffolder <<<<  -Name Views -Scaffolder MvcScaffolding.Views -SolutionWide -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-DefaultScaffolder], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.SetDefaultScaffolderCmdlet

Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get install path because packages root directory has not been supplied
at G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.4\tools\init.ps1:37 Char:22
+ Set-DefaultScaffolder <<<<  -Name Action -Scaffolder MvcScaffolding.Action -SolutionWide -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-DefaultScaffolder], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.SetDefaultScaffolderCmdlet

Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get install path because packages root directory has not been supplied
at G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.4\tools\init.ps1:38 Char:22
+ Set-DefaultScaffolder <<<<  -Name UnitTest -Scaffolder MvcScaffolding.ActionUnitTest -SolutionWide -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-DefaultScaffolder], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.SetDefaultScaffolderCmdlet

Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get install path because packages root directory has not been supplied
at G:\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.4\tools\init.ps1:42 Char:22
+ Set-DefaultScaffolder <<<<  -Name View -Scaffolder $viewScaffolder -SolutionWide -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-DefaultScaffolder], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.SetDefaultScaffolderCmdlet

Successfully added 'EntityFramework 4.1.10715.0' to MvcApplication1.
Successfully added 'T4Scaffolding 1.0.4' to MvcApplication1.
Successfully added 'MvcScaffolding 1.0.4' to MvcApplication1.

PM>
```

Does anyone who know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!